# Deep Learning Classification CIFAR-10 Low Validation Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My validation score after 5 epochs is about 0.07 and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. I am trying to learn generated image classifier.

## In[1]:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
```

## In[2]:

```
(features_train, label_train), (features_test, label_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

## In[3]:

```
features_train.shape
```

## In[4]:

```
features_test.shape
```

## In[5]:

```
batch_size = 16
img_height = 32
img_width = 32
```

## In[6]:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

## In[7]:

```
train_img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                  width_shift_range = 0.1,
                                  height_shift_range = 0.1,
                                  horizontal_flip = True)
```

## In[8]:

```
val_img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
```

## In[9]:

```
train_data_gen = train_img_gen.flow(features_train, label_train, batch_size = batch_size)
```

## In[10]:

```
val_data_gen = train_img_gen.flow(features_test, label_test, batch_size = batch_size)
```

## In[11]:

```
train_data_gen
```

## In[12]:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

## In[13]:

```
np.random.seed(8)
tf.random.set_seed(8)
```

## In[14]:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 3)),
                            layers.MaxPooling2D(),
                            layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
                            layers.MaxPooling2D(),
                            layers.Flatten(),
                            layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
                            layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
```

## In[15]:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
```

## In[16]:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## In[17]:

```
model.summary()
```

## In[18]:

```
model.fit(train_data_gen, 
          steps_per_epoch=len(features_train)//batch_size, 
          epochs=5, 
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
         validation_steps=len(features_test)//batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard 'accuracy' metric is not supposed to work as the model's output is one-hot encoded but your labels are integer-encoded. So, try using `sparse_categorical_accuracy` when compiling your model, like this:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

Also, It would be better to train for more epochs, to achieve a better performance. For example, 100 epochs:

```
model.fit(train_data_gen, 
          steps_per_epoch=len(features_train)//batch_size, 
          epochs=100, 
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
         validation_steps=len(features_test)//batch_size)
```

Another thing, the number of filters for the `Conv2D` layers seems too large for such a straight-forward image classification task. And it would also be better if you use more convolution layers, than using more number of filters. Again, this can cause the model to overfit, so try using a `Dropout` layer in the end to tackle that issue. Like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
```

Comment: Yap! It's now 6.650 what is should be! Thanks!
So, one-hot encoding is [1, 0, 0, 0] something like that and integer-encoding is something like [0, 1, 2, 3] like in NLP, am I right?

Comment: @EgorCry if you have 3 labels, then one-hot encoding for [1] would be [0,1,0], the one-hot encoding for [2] would be [0,0,1], [0] would be [1,0,0]

Comment: When you pass metric as `accuracy`, it will be converted to a suitable one. Check: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/4098cefe29aea05ba80faff878cec464f1b3a2e9/keras/engine/training.py#L569-L588